# Generating the key generated with Python in SQL Server

Tags: sql, python-3.x, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am running the Python code shown here:

```
import hashlib

s = "8508688361-CTU50066523"
print(hashlib.sha256(s.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
print(int(hashlib.sha256(s.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16))
```

I am getting these results:

1. print return :

   ```
   60f95246d58d304d29f71f73f1b5615dcb28b0f2a82e592b03df2536a461f718
   ```
2. print return :

   ```
   43862546236009694287120913811214596446612599063870465835323810000576872314648
   ```

I can get the same result of the 1st print with this T-SQL code:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(1000), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', '8508688361-CTU50066523'), 2)
```

T-SQL returns :

```
60F95246D58D304D29F71F73F1B5615DCB28B0F2A82E592B03DF2536A461F718
```

However, I could not get the 2nd print result in python with T-SQL - can you help in any way?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Please read carefully my answer, I think that the hexadecimal value you provided is too large to be directly converted to a BIGINT in SQL Server. The maximum value for a BIGINT in SQL Server is 9223372036854775807.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the hexadecimal value you provided is too large to be directly converted to a `BIGINT` in SQL Server. The maximum value for a `BIGINT` in SQL Server is 9223372036854775807.

You may consider storing the result as a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` data type instead.

```sql
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100) = '8508688361-CTU50066523'

DECLARE @sha256 VARBINARY(MAX)
SET @sha256 = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @s)

DECLARE @hexString VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @hexString = UPPER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @sha256, 2))

SELECT @hexString
```

I tried to calculate the SHA-256 hash using the `HASHBYTES` function and store it in the `@sha256` variable, then converted it the `VARBINARY` `@sha256` value to a hexadecimal string using `CONVERT` and store it in `@hexString`.